# Get application/program which created a file in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have several programs (.exe) installed on my computer which create ".dat" files. One of them creates very large files.

I want to delete only the files created by this program.

Is there a way in PS to know which program has created a file?

I try to filter them in following code:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.dat" -Recurse -Force |'
Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $limit -and $_.LastAccessTime -lt $limit2 -and $_.Attributes -notmatch "Offline" } |'
Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible unless your program somehow stamps a property onto *.dat* file which you would then read.

Use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) if you want to find out which executable creates the file in question.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to execute the ".exe programms" under different credentials, one different user per exe. Then you can use [get-acl](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/04/15/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-determine-the-owner-of-a-file.aspx) to identify who created each file:

```
$OWNER = "xxxx"
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter "*.dat" -Recurse -Force |'
Where-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName -eq $OWNER -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit -and $_.LastAccessTime -lt $limit2 -and $_.Attributes -notmatch "Offline" } |'
Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using ProcessMonitor ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645). This will show all file system activity and will quickly show you which processes are accessing which files.